# How to make a multiset from multiple sets in R?

Tags: r, set, multiset

I have multiple sets and I would like to build their multiset in R. Is there any solution for that? For example, I have 3 sets:

```
set1 <- c(1,3,6)
set2 <- c(1,2,6,7,9)
set3 <- c(1,3,7)
```

and I would like to have a multiset like

```
multiset = {1:3,2:1,3:2,6:2,7:2,9:1}
```

where `1:3` means that element `1` is repeated `3` times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the following what you want?

```r
set1 <- c(1,3,6)
set2 <- c(1,2,6,7,9)
set3 <- c(1,3,7)

tb <- table(c(set1, set2, set3))
paste(names(tb), m[,1], collapse=",", sep=":")
```

#### Edit

Following the comment, that the output should be manipulatable, one can easily put it in a matrix:

```r
tb <- table(c(set1, set2, set3))

mat <- cbind(no=names(tb), freq=tb)
```

And if needed, convert the character columns to numeric:

```r
apply(mat, 2, as.numeric)
#>      no freq
#> [1,]  1    3
#> [2,]  2    1
#> [3,]  3    2
#> [4,]  6    2
#> [5,]  7    2
#> [6,]  9    1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It prints the thing that I mentioned in my question, but it is not manipulatable. I think this command works perfectly (`m <- as.matrix(table(c(set1, set2, set3)))`) if I can have it in the first column the elements. I mean currently `m` has one column, but it would be great to make it with two columns

Comment: Two columns is even easier, but you asked for a special printed output, not a matrix with columns.